# Are flight tickets from or to the US purchased through Vayama refundable free of charge within 24 hours (ticket was purchased > 1 week before)?

Tags: usa, air-travel, tickets, cancellations

Are flight tickets from or to the United States purchased through Vayama refundable free of charge within 24 hours, assuming that the ticket was purchased at least 1 week prior to the flight?

https://s1.travix.com/vayama/US/vaycom-conditions-en.pdf (this link was found on vayama.com on the ticket order page:; Travix manages Vayama's website according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travix_International_B.V.) states:

> If you decide to change or cancel a confirmed booking for air travel, and such changes or cancellation is
>   allowed, Vayama will charge you a fee of up to **$100 per person**. Note that Vayama will charge you this fee
>   even if you cancel within 24 hours of receiving your booking confirmation.

However the ticket conditions state:

> [sic] TICKETS TO FROM USA A **FULL REFUND WITHOUT SERVICE
>   CHARGE** WILL BE GIVEN IF THE REFUND REQUEST IS
>   SUBMITTED WITHIN24 HOURS AFTER TICKET PURCHASE
>   AND THE RESERVATION WAS MADE ONE WEEK OR MORE
>   PRIOR TO A FLIGHTS SCHEDULED DEPARTURE.

Ticket conditions can be viewed in the order page:

[image]

So I am confused.

Comment: Are you going to believe the ticket conditions as stated by the ticket issuer at the time you bought the ticket, or a third party site which publishes an undated, unauthenticated copy of the ticket issuer's conditions with no accountability?

Comment: @GregHewgill all the information comes from the third party website

Comment: Did you look on Vayama's web site? There is info about cancelling in their [Frequently asked questions](https://www.vayama.com/customer-service/faq#!708|15000003566|) section.

Comment: @GregHewgill all the quotes mentioned in the question came from Vayama's website.

Comment: You said earlier that all the information comes from a third party site (who is travix.com?). You're contradicting yourself. Not spending any more time on this question.

Comment: @GregHewgill sorry I thought that by third party site you meant Vayama (which is a third party site from the airline's standpoint), and not Travix. Travix manages Vayama's websites, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travix_International_B.V.. So it is not accurate to refer Travix to as a third-party from Vayama's standpoint, which you seem to have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOT [answers](https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/refunds) this question.

> What if I purchased or reserved my ticket through a travel agent or online travel agency?

> The 24-hour refund/reservation requirement for airlines does not apply to tickets booked through online travel agencies, travel agents, or other third-party agents.  However, these agents are free to apply the same or similar procedures to provide equivalent or similar customer service.

> If you purchased your ticket through an online travel agency (or other agent), you should contact the travel agent directly to obtain a refund before contacting the airline.

Yet another reason why you should never use these services.